# Pass variable into python script from R using system2()

Tags: python, r

I have seen various versions of this question, but have not been able to figure out how to pass numeric variables into Python from R using system2()

For example suppose I have the following python script as Test.py.

```
a = 1
b = 2
def add(a,b):
    print a + b
```

I can run this in R with

```
pypath = './Test.py'
system2('python', args=(sprintf('"%1$s"',pypath)))
```

but what if I wanted to pass the values of a and b in, and have the values returned within R to an R object? Something like,

```
a = 1
b = 2
d = system2('python',args = (sprintf('"%1$s" "%2$s" "%3$s"',pypath,a,b)))
```

I have tried a variety of ways of doing this, but have failed. I know the above is wrong, I just can't figure out how to pass in a and b, much less return a value

My questions are (1) is it possible? and (2) how do you do it?

Comment: Yes it's possible. But before you start with this, I think it would benefit to take a look at [IPython](http://ipython.org/), which was built pretty much for [such integration purposes](https://youtu.be/F4rFuIb1Ie4?t=2132)

Comment: Passing a and b is easy. You don't even need to use sptintf as you are doing right now. args argument takes in an array of characters so it you just to `system2('python', args = c('./Test.py', as.character(a), as.character(b)))`. To write into a file, as a workaround you can use `>` to direct the output to a temp file and read from the file with R. It'll be slower but it'll work

Comment: Thanks @OganM. That is exactly what I was looking for. How do I use > to direct the output to a file using system2()? I have seen it used it with system, but not system2().

Comment: just add it as another argument. `system2('yourcommand',c('ARG1', 'ARG2', '>/targetDir/targetFile'))`

Comment: If you add this as the answer, I can upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System2 takes in an array of characters. So instead of trying to feed an entire string, you can just do

```
system2('python', args = c('./Test.py', as.character(a), as.character(b)))
```

One way of transferring the output to R is to use ">" to write it to a file then reading the file from R. (I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way to do this).

```
system2('python',args = c('/Test.py', as.character(a), as.character(b), '>/targetDir/targetFile'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always just concatenated my whole string together...

```
a <- "/path/to/python"
b <- "script_to_call.py"
c <- 1

system(paste0(a, " ", b, " ", c))
```